# Где править генераторы кода в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio умеет, например, создавать обработчики событий автоматически. Я могу создать обработчик прямо из XAML разметки, при этом в коде создается что-то типа

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Но у нас стиль кода подразумевает отсутствие модификатора доступа private, так как он используется по умолчанию. Так вот, вопрос: **как научить студию при автоматическом создании обработчиков не добавлять слово `private`?**

Comment: переопределение не поможет ?

Answer (score 1):

Задавать параметры для генерации кода Visual Studio можно в окне "Tools->Options-Text Editor->C#->Code Style" и еще в соседних узлах относительно узла Code Style.

На сколько я знаю там нельзя задать параметры для генераций событий.

Также есть [расширение для Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/14f62cb9-b559-4bad-9388-37da2150e238), но оно работает только с WinForms (автор говорит что для WPF редактора невозможно реализовать данное расширение).

Для общего стиля кода в команде использую [ReSharper с общими настройками](https://habrahabr.ru/post/262383/).